# openssl_encrypt is not recognized by PHP

Tags: php, windows, apache, openssl, php-openssl

I can run `openssl_encrypt ($string, $method, $pass);` when I run it through php cmd. However when I run it via Apache http server it throw the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt() in D:\...\lab.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\...\lab.php on line 2
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: You need to change(php.ini)  ;extension=php_mcrypt.dll to extension=php_mcrypt.dll 
 then restart your apache server

Comment: @RaviHirani No you don't. OpenSSL has no relationship to mcrypt.

Comment: @duskwuff: Yeah. I get it. my mistake. Extension should be extension=php_openssl.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that apache wasn't installed completely and there was some missing files of it.

so I reinstalled the apache and problem was gone.